# How to spin up VM instance using new version of container image

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have an app with a Dockerfile that gets auto-built on Dockerhub when I push code to my repository.  It is tagged with the `latest` tag.  I would like then to reset my GCE VM instance to use that version.

I have reserved IP address for that VM, so I would like to be able to just replace the image and keep everything else the same.

It seems right now that I must create a new instance and I cannot tell it to pull the `latest` image again.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up setting up autobuild docker to apply a tag based on a git tag and then use gcloud command `gcloud compute instances update-container --container-image=myImage instanceName`.